# Regarding the shift operator and its precedence in C++

Tags: c++

While programming some registers in a testcase, I came across this statement. I'm new to C++. Sorry in advance if this is a dumb question.

```
base_width = 13; // assume 32 bit number
base_width +=  (base_width << 6) << 5;
```

Considering `base_width` is a 32-bit `unsigned int`, what should be the value of `base_width` after the above executes? I tried with different compilers and it gives different results. According to C++ standards what should be the answer and why?

Comment: What did you get when you *ran* this (and what **type** is `base_width` ? It makes a difference. If its an 8 bit unsigned char, you'll get zero. If its a *signed* integral type, you'll get undefined behavior if you shift into the sign bit, but the leap from 8 to even 16 bits with a starting value of 13 makes that somewhat irrelevant right now). More code and context please.

Comment: What results did you get, and with what compilers?

Comment: Note that `(base_width << 6) << 5` is the same as `base_width << 11`. This is well defined, and if you get different results on different compiler then there's probably something else you're not telling us.

Comment: `(base_width << 6) << 5` should be `base_width << (6 + 5)` == `base_width << 11` for 32-bit and `base_width = 13` it doesn't  overflow so it should give same result

Comment: You've added "considering base width is 32 unsigned int", but it's hard for us to trust that when you haven't posted the actual code you're using. Can you copy/paste complete, compilable, runnable code that demonstrates different output on different compilers?

Comment: ok. after the question-update the comments spell it out for you if it is, in fact, 32-bit `unsigned int`.

Comment: sorry i forgot the "+=" and put it initially as only "=". Now corrected...

Comment: It's `+=` now? The problem is almost certainly not due to the shift behavior. You most likely didn't test the same code on each compiler.

Comment: And now... its 26624 + 13, or 26637. Assuming the latest question-update is the *last* one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the shifts in binary:

```
base_width = 13; // 1101 (base 2)

(base_width << 6) // 1101000000 (base 2)

(base_width << 6) << 5 // 110100000000000 (base 2) = 26624
```

Result:

```
base_width += (base_width << 6) << 5; // 13 + 26624 = 26637
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify:

```
base_width = 13; // assume 32 bit number
base_width += (base_width << 6) << 5;

base_width = 13 + ((13 << 6) << 5);

base_width = 13 + (832 << 5);

base_width = 13 + 26624;

base_width = 26637;
```

For a final result of `base_width` being 26637. According to a standard's conforming implementation, at least.

If you're getting different results on different compilers, then either a) you're compilers are junk (not very likely), or b) your code is different than what you posted (more likely).